# sql plan baseline information for particular sql_ID

Tags: oracle11g, baseline

how can we see list of all plans for that optimizer is currently having in SQL plan history (accepted and unaccepted plans) for particular sql_id from sqlplus?

Answer (score 1):

A plan is accepted if and only if it is in the plan baseline. The plan history for a statement contains all plans, both accepted and unaccepted. After the optimizer generates the first accepted plan in a plan baseline, every subsequent unaccepted plan is added to the plan history, awaiting verification, but is not in the SQL plan baseline.

Starting in Oracle Database 12c, the SMB stores the plans rows for new plans added to the plan history of a SQL statement. The [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_SQL_PLAN_BASELINE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_spm.htm#TGSQL645) function fetches and displays the plan from the SMB. For plans created before Oracle Database 12c, the function must compile the SQL statement and generate the plan because the SMB does not store the rows.

To display a plan

```
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
FROM   V$SQL s, DBA_SQL_PLAN_BASELINES b, 
       TABLE(
         DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_SQL_PLAN_BASELINE(b.sql_handle,b.plan_name,'basic') 
       ) t
WHERE  s.EXACT_MATCHING_SIGNATURE=b.SIGNATURE
AND    b.PLAN_NAME=s.SQL_PLAN_BASELINE
AND    s.SQL_ID='31d96zzzpcys9';
```